# Javascript change images based on timer

Tags: javascript, html

I have following HTML code snippet:

```
<div>
    <div onload="startTimer()">
        <img id="img-showcase" src="/assets/img1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function displayNextImage() {
        x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
        document.getElementById("img-showcase").src = images[x];
    }

    function startTimer() {
        setInterval(displayNextImage, 3000);
    }

    var images = [], x = 0;
    images[0] = "/assets/img1.jpg";
    images[1] = "/assets/img2.jpg";
    images[2] = "/assets/img3.jpg";
</script>
```

I wish to make img change dinamically based on setInterval timer... What am i missing?

Comment: Side note when you increment `x` doing something with the [modulus operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp) can be a little cleaner `x = (x + 1) % images.length;`

Comment: divs do not have onload event

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an "onload" event to a div. Try moving this to the body and it should work.

Comment: Can you provide some documentation to prove that claim? It's better to show real proof on SO than just saying "trust me".

Comment: @takendarkk it is a fact.... I will be his documentation source.

Comment: Sure - check out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp and look at the "Supported HTML tags:" section

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

I can keep going...